Flexbox with wrapped text leaves undesired empty horizontal space
I'm trying to create a printable dynamic HTML form but I cannot arrange the questions and answers on the page the way I want.
I have a flex container for a pair of question and answer and I expect the text in either of them to be wrapped if it's too long. The issue is that once the text is wrapped, it leaves a lot of empty horizontal space. This is not my desired outcome, especially for the question (left).
How can I preferably keep using CSS flexbox and text-wrap while not having that extra white space? I prefer the solution to be with pure HTML and CSS and I am hesitant to implement any JavaScript due to performance concerns.

<div class="container">
    <div class="question">Breathing Circuit for Bedside Ventilator:</div>
    <div class="answer">Quantity Other Than Physician Order (5)</div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.7em;
}

.container .question {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  text-wrap: balance;
}

.container .answer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-wrap: pretty;
}

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/n6883s
